# Reference type inside value type in swift?

Tags: swift, class, struct

I have a struct User and Class account

```
struct User
{
  var name: string
  var account: Account
}

Class Account
{
  var balance: Double
  var accountNumber: String
  init(bal: Double, accNum: String)
 {
     self.balance = bal
     self.accountNumber: accNum
 }
}
```

I am creating an instance for User and passing to multiple methods. It is clear that a copy will be created for the user but what about the account property inside the user object.

**Questions:**

**1. Every time the user instance is passed to someother method the retain count of the account instance will be incremented?**

**2. At the end of the method ie before exiting the method the user instance will be deallocated and the retain count of the account will be reduced?**

Comment: Curious  - why isn't `Account` a `struct` instead of a `class`?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Every time the user instance is passed to someother method the retain count of the account instance will be incremented?

Correct.

> 2. At the end of the method ie before exiting the method the user instance will be deallocated and the retain count of the account will be reduced?

You have the right idea, but this isn't necessarily true. The User object may be destroyed much earlier than when the method exits. But you're correct that whenever it is destroyed, the retain count will be reduced.

That said, retain counts are an internal implementation detail that mean basically nothing. The better way to say all of the above is "a strong reference will be made to..." and " a strong reference will be removed from." I know that sound almost exactly like "retain count" but it may or may not actually result in the `retainCount` field in the underlying data structure literally being incremented or decremented. There are a lots of ways that expensive operation might be dodged. But your basic understanding is correct.